# UITableView with XIB for iPhone 5 hides cells in iPhone 4

Tags: uitableview, frame

I have a XIB with a view set for "retina 4-inch full screen". I have a tableview in it.
In iPhone 5 works perfectly.
I have a translucent image at the navigation bar.

In iPhone 4 the tableView "hides" the bottom cells.

I've already try to set the tableview frame = screenBounds, but without success.

Any help?

Comment: Are you using Autolayout in the XIB? If so, simply set constraints to set the top and bottom edges of the table view to be flexible.  If not, do similar with the springs and struts.

Comment: perfect! I've removed auto-layout from tableView and it works great :)